# How to remove blank space from array value with javascript-jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I get a number value from an array and when I append to the DOM I get a blank space before the value that I need to remove.

The result should look like this. `data-filter-class="["4"]"`

```
for (var i=0, len=strArray.length; i<len; i++) {
                            
    thepost=String(strArray[i]); 
    thepost = thepost.split(",");
    pid=thepost[9]
    pid=String(pid)
    pid=pid.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    pid='["'+pid+'"]'
    console.log(pid) // here I get ["4"]
```

and then I create a variable like this

```
html +='<li data-filter-class="'+pid+'" class="test">'

console.log(html) // here I get <li data-filter-class="["4"]" class="test"> as I should
```

and then I append it to my list.

But when I then look at the code after it is appended I get a blank space before the value?

Then it look like this

```
<li data-filter-class="[" 4"]" class="test">
```

So instead of `"["4"]"` I get `"[" 4"]"`

So how do I remove the blank space?

---

#### Solved

I finally got it working with this. It should be `'["4"]'`, my mistake!

```
pid='\'["'+pid+'"]\''
data-filter-class='+''+pid+''+'
```

And it becomes `data-filter-class='["4"]'`

Comment: What is strArray here?

Comment: Do a `trim()` on the pid like `pid = pid.trim();` - might help if you have space chars at the start of end of your pid string.

Comment: Also, if you can please post an example that we can test here.

Comment: thepost[9] might also contain invisible non-space chars.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

or

```
array = array.map(function (el) {
return el.trim();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

i am sure your problem isnt with the trim part may be try to create the li element in this way please

```
    let row=document.createElement("li");
    row.setAttribute("data-filter-class",pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently desired `<li data-filter-class="["4"]"` doesn't look like a good idea. When I see `"["4"]"` it looks like something wrong, because outer quote marks are the same as inner ones. Are you sure that it will be read like `["4"]` in the end of the day?

May be the interpreter sees the `"["4"]"` and reads it like two separate values `"["` and `4"]"` and therefore inserts a space?.. Who knows.

I would either try escape inner quote marks to get it `"[\"4\"]"`, or, maybe use different inner quotes altogether: `"['4']"`

Then your code would be like this:

```
 pid='[\\"'+pid+'\\"]'   // for eascaped double quotes inside
```

or like this:

```
 pid='[\''+pid+'\']'    // for single quotes inside
```

But this has to be check.

Comment: Yes you where right, it should be '["4"]', my misstake :-) Thanks.